# how can i change my search with search position by id?

Tags: android, json

I have two spinner the second one is to link with the first one with position and a list view that shows a CV when you click on an item that is linked with position too, I want to replace it will be linked with id, how can I do please

this is my code  spinner

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
 position, long id) {
            if(arrayListTache.size() > position)
            {
                spinner_tache.setSelection(position);
                pos = position;
                valueInteger = arrayListInteger.get(position);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

my code onclick list view

```
SubjectListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
       pos, long id) {
                    String selectedItem = 
       parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        Intent intent = new 
        Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Position" , String.valueOf(id));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    // insert();

                }
            });
```

Comment: did you add any adapter?  then change the method named getItemId return the id from there.
then from OnItemClick method get the Id and do next

Comment: I have a adapter ..  I did not understand sorry

Comment: can you share the code of adapter?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q6LhG8NCX7P51bL2LeRwDzeSA7lFxShq and https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RofoRh2ux-aac7QsAM_R5loA-5-O4WF3

Comment: i change this ??   @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }